# How to position the results div beneath the search input with the same width of the input?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a search box that shows some results while typing.

Here is a static example:

```
<form method="GET" class="my-form">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <span>
            <input  type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">       </span>
        <span>
            <input type="submit" value="search" class="search" >
        </span>
        <div class="results">
            <ul>
                <li>first</li>
                <li>second</li>
                <li>third</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.my-form{width:100%}

.search-wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    display: table;
    position:relative;
    padding:2%
}

span{display:table-cell;margin-top:10%}

span:first-of-type{width:75%}

.search-query{
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    padding-left: 3%;
    width:100%
}

.search{
    background: #ea7d20;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
   width:100%
}

.results{
    width:75%;
    background:#888;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%
}
```

I want to position the `results` div beneath the search input and have the same width of that input , It should be responsive too.

Here is a live preview: https://jsfiddle.net/nner02rk/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` is inside the `search-wrapper`. But this div is affected by a padding of 2%. That is why your values are not responding as you expecte them to.

```
.results{  
  width: 70%;
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3.5%;
  top: 100%;
  }
```

To validate the alignment, you can set the top value to 71%

Hope this helps :)

```css
.my-form{width:100%}
.search-wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    display: table;
    position:relative;
    padding:2%
}
span{display:table-cell;margin-top:10%}
span:first-of-type{width:75%}
.search-query{
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    padding-left: 3%;
    
    width:100%
}
.search{
    background: #ea7d20;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
   width:100%
}
.results{  
  width: 70%;
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3.5%;
  top: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<form method="GET" class="my-form">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
   <span>
      <input  type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">       </span>
  <span>
      <input type="submit" value="search" class="search" >
    </span>
  <div class="results">
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I mean the search input  `<input  type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">` , Not the whole `search-wrapper`

Comment: So you want the results div to be as the search bar width?

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle just keep the result class width to 100%..

```
.results{
  margin-left: 4%;
  width:70%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nner02rk/8/

Comment: I mean the search input  `<input  type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">` , Not the whole `search-wrapper`